# php bad words replacement with stars and output array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Following `php` function is being used to replace bad words with starts but I need one additional parameters that will describe either bad words found or not .

```
    $badwords = array('dog', 'dala', 'bad3', 'ass');
    $text = 'This is a dog. . Grass. is good but ass is bad.';
    print_r( filterBadwords($text,$badwords));


    function filterBadwords($text, array $badwords, $replaceChar = '*') {
$repu = preg_replace_callback(array_map(function($w) { return '/\b' . preg_quote($w, '/') . '\b/i'; }, $badwords),
        function($match) use ($replaceChar) {
                    return str_repeat($replaceChar, strlen($match[0])); },
                    $text

                    );
 return array('error' =>'Match/No Match', 'text' => $repu );   
}// Func
```

Output if badwords found should be like

> Array ( [error] => Match[text] => Bad word dog match. )

If no badwords found then

> Array ( [error] => No Match[text] => Bad word match. )

Comment: on which basis you can decide string as a bad word?

Comment: if any word of $text match with $badwords it means this word is bad

Comment: so what problem you are facing?

Comment: failed to use a variable on the place of "Match/No Match"

Comment: Your best solution is always going to be manual moderation.  There's no perfect automated solution (See "Scunthorpe problem")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
function filterBadwords($text, array $badwords, $replaceChar = '*') {
   //new bool var to see if there was any match
    $matched = false;
    $repu = preg_replace_callback(array_map(
        function($w)
        {
            return '/\b' . preg_quote($w, '/') . '\b/i'; 
        }, $badwords),
        //pass the $matched by reference
        function($match) use ($replaceChar, &$matched)
        {
            //if the $match array is not empty update $matched to true
            if(!empty($match))
            {
                $matched = true;
            }
            return str_repeat($replaceChar, strlen($match[0]));
        }, $text);
    //return response based on the bool value of $matched
    if($matched)
    {
        $return = array('error' =>'Match', 'text' => $repu );
    }
    else
    {
        $return = array('error' =>'No Match', 'text' => $repu );
    }
    return $return;   
}
```

This uses `reference` and `if` condition to see if there were any matches and then returns response based on that.

Output(if matched):

```
array (size=2)
  'error' => string 'Match' (length=5)
  'text' => string 'This is a ***. . Grass. is good but *** is bad.'
```

Output(if none matched):

```
array (size=2)
  'error' => string 'No Match' (length=8)
  'text' => string 'This is a . . Grass. is good but  is bad.'
```

Comment: wao . what a great solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$badwords = array('dog', 'dala', 'bad3', 'ass');
$text = 'This is a dog. . Grass. is good but ass is bad.';
$res=is_badword($badwords,$text);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($res);


function is_badword($badwords, $text) 
{    
    $res=array('No Error','No Match');
    foreach ($badwords as $name) {
        if (stripos($text, $name) !== FALSE) {
            $res=array($name,'Match');
            return $res;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

?>

Output: 

Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => Match
)
```